# Website Inaccessible to US Visitors

Tags: malware, country-specific, block

I help to manage a website based in Latin America and have run into an interesting issue I have no explanation for. The site was built in Wordpress using both Gutenberg and the backend editor, with only a small handful of simple plugins to facilitate easier website organization. The GOTMLS.net plugin is used for malware protection, which could be a factor. For some reason, when a user attempts to enter the site from a US computer, this notification pops up:

[image: Site blocked notification]

I have tested this with many other computers connected to different networks and the result is always the same. However, whenever I have used a VPN to connect to the site through countries like Japan, Poland and El Salvador, everything works as intended. Is there any reason why US visitors are being blocked? Nothing was coded in intentionally to cause this to happen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This message is from Cloudflare, so you either have a Cloudflare account and are using it to protect your website, or your web hosting service provided this for you. At the bottom of that message is a Cloudflare Ray ID (that you blurred), so you can create a filter for that in your Cloudflare account under `Security Center -> Security Insights` to see what triggered that as per [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/unable-to-access-the-website/575761) Cloudflare thread. If you don't have access to a Cloudflare account, then provide this information to your web hosting company's support.